# how to use sessions in express, couchDB, and node.js

Tags: javascript, session, node.js, express

so I basically want to use sessions to store the users name and check to see if the user logged in or not. If not, the page will redirect to the login page.

I am using Node.js,express,and couchDB.

Here is how i set up my session so far

```
var MemoryStore = require('connect').session.MemoryStore;
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ 
    secret: "keyboard cat", 
    store: new MemoryStore({ 
        reapInterval: 60000 * 10
    })
}));
```

To store something in the session, i use the following code right?

```
req.session = {user:name);
```

So the session variable seems to work on my login page. I successfully store the user's name into the session However, when I try to access the session variable on another page, it gives me the error

```
Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

all i'm doing is:

```
if (req.session.user){
```

Why is this error happening? are sessions not global to the whole app? Or am I missing something entirely here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `req.session = {user:name);` part of your code is no longer correct. I assume this worked in an older version of express, but now to avoid an error, you will need to use `req.session.user=name;`. If you don't, methods on req.session will be overwritten.

Answer (score 71):

If you're doing `app.use(app.router)` before the lines that set up the cookie and session handling, try moving it to after them. That fixed the same problem for me.

Comment: Ok yeah. Everything works now. Idk why it wasn't earlier. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Just joining the others who have stumbled upon your answer when need of help... thanks!

Comment: @Ernesto11 you should give this a green check :) It worked for me as well

Comment: no work for me. Only adding it to the express.createServer() call seems to make it happen :-/

Comment: Just to clarify, I had the same problem but this doesn't fix that at all. But I discovered you have to put the cookieParser, session and router at the end of the configuration in that order. hope someone more helps!

Comment: You need `app.use(express.cookieParser());` before `app.use(express.session({ secret: '}{91`/,48+F{tf2'}));`

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to solve the exact same problem for he last few hour.

Try initializing your server like that:

```
var app = express.createServer(
express.cookieParser(),
express.session({ secret: "crazysecretstuff"})
  );
```

That should work.

Comment: I tried that and it's still not working. Why would I have to initialize my server like that? it says in the express documentation to use

Comment: app.use(express.cookieParser());
   app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat" }));

Comment: Both are valid ways to initialize middleware with express.js. The only difference for me is that sessions only work if I initialize them in app.createServer. Might be a bug.

Comment: Works for me, thank you. The main idea IMHO is to 'use()' cookieParser and session before all other 'uses'. My code:

  `var app = express.createServer();
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secret key' }));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue of getting undefined for session variable which I knew was set ok.

In my case it turned out to be caused by cross origin request, I had forgotten the withCredentials header on the request.

So for example in my client side Angular app I needed to do this:

```
var config = { withCredentials: true };
return $http.get(appConfig.apiUrl + '/orders', config);
```

and in Express this:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

the `sessionSecret` in the configuration (config.json?) should be non-empty:

`sessionSecret: "something other than an empty string",`