# Closure find node.js, mongodb, express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, closures

Please help me. I need variable in my search use post:

```
app.post('/find', function(req, res) {
    var id_school = req.body.std_id;
    console.log('show '+ id_sekolah);
    db.collection('ak_test_score', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({'std_id':id_school}).toArray(function(err, level) {
            var a = level.std_id;
            var b = level.school_name;
        });
    });
    res.redirect('/test_score'); // send to my page to get
};

var test = a;  // not defined variable a not have

app.get('/test_score', function(req, res) {
    var id_school = test;
    console.log('show '+ id_sekolah);
    db.collection('ak_test_score', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({'std_id':id_school}).toArray(function(err, level) {
             res.send(level)
        });
    });
};
```

I am using this for a website search using post.

Comment: I think you couldn't redirect using `post` method (if I understand what are you looking for). If you want to pass variable use sessions, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599083/how-to-use-sessions-in-express-couchdb-and-node-js

Comment: thanks for u attention but i dont get answer for my code...i use for search but my code use post in html so data not show in get..

Comment: You can't initialize `test` variable this way. `a` will be undefined.

Comment: yeah in my code have 2 method post and get, for input data use post and for show data use get..but i have trouble closure my variable in post method not have in get method..

Comment: Use session, store variable in post stage and retrive it in get stage.

Comment: hmm... i am confuse to use it (T_T)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.post('/find', function(req, res) {
   var id_school = req.body.std_id;
   console.log('show '+ id_sekolah);
   db.collection('ak_test_score', function(err, collection) {
      collection.find({'std_id':id_school}).toArray(function(err, level) {
        var a = level.std_id;
        app.set('data',a);
        var b = level.school_name;

        });
});
   res.redirect('/test_score'); ///// send to my page to get
};


 app.get('/test_score', function(req, res) {
    var id_school = app.get('data');
    console.log('show '+ id_sekolah);
    db.collection('ak_test_score', function(err, collection) {
      collection.find({'std_id':id_school}).toArray(function(err, level) {
           res.send(level)
        });
});

};
```

Comment: hello thanks for u help i got it my problem brother my data not in variable a, i change my code in find data use 


db.collection('ak_test_score', function(err, collection) {collection.findOne({'std_id': {'$regex': id_school}}, function (err, level) {

and its work thanks u

Comment: but i have new problem lol.. if my search = null my node.js is stack... i use if (level = null) { }else{} my app. undefined T_T hik hik